# Level order binary tree insert with 0-children subtrees

Tags: c, algorithm, structure, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to create algorithm that inserts values to binary tree in level order but when the value is 0 then the node has no children

Example:

```
Elements: [7,6,4,3,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0]
How values in tree would be placed:
         7
        / \
       6   4
      /   / \
     3   0   1
    /  \    / \
   1    2  0   0
  / \  / \
 0  0 0   5
         / \
        0   0
```

I don't know how to transform BFS algorithm to make it "dodge" inserting in 0-value nodes.

Comment: Fyi, your tree doesn't match your element list. You list has no 9, but your tree does, and you list has two 1's, where your tree has one.

Comment: Haha, yes, edited

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your tree is bad constructed, I don't know how after the first `3` you continue adding the `0` below the `4`, shouldn't it be the right child of `6`?

```
Elements: [7,6,4,3,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0]
How values in tree would be placed:
          7
         / `----.
        6       4
       / \     / `--.
      3   0   1     1
     / \     / \   / \
    2   0   0   0 0   0
   / \  
  5   0   
 / \
0   ?
```

Not?
In order to be able to help you, You need to have a clear idea of what output you do expect.